# Анимация при переходе между формами

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Вот есть такая проблема нужно при переходе с главной формы на другие показывать стандартную анимацию кружочек крутится, вот код но анимация не отображается. Параметер в PushAsync который отвечает за базовую анимацию есть true.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void PlayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PlayPage(),true);
        }
        private async void RateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new RatePage(),true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Анимация, для которой вы указываете значение `true`, - это анимация перехода между страницами. Чтобы отобразить крутящийся кружочек, вам необходимо использовать ActivityIndicator. Пример использования можете посмотреть [здесь](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/run-and-stop-activity-indicator-in-xamarin-forms/). Отобразите его на странице, с которой происходит переход, или создайте отдельную страницу, которая будет отображать `ActivityIndicator`